# При загрузке страницы с overflow: scroll прыгает скролл.

Tags: html, css

Есть элементы на странице с `overflow: scroll`. Если контента меньше чем необходимо для скролла - при загрузке скролл появляется на доли секунд и исчезает. В резльтате этого части страницы заметно дергаются при загрузке. Возможно ли от этого избавиться? Спасибо.

Comment: Внутри этих блоков используется подключаемый шрифт на тексте?

Comment: Используется, но он подключен и обьявлен глобально, для всех страниц.

Comment: @mJeevas Небольшое уточнение. Проверил - это происходит только в хроме. Лиса так не делает.

Comment: Попробуйте отключить шрифты и посмотреть, сохранилась ли проблема. Возможно, они не успевают подгрузиться и текст у вас согласно вашим настройкам сначала появляется с другим шрифтом более "большим"

Comment: @mJeevas вроде бы прошелся по всем местам со шрифтами - не оно. Буду копать далее.